# Display Product Variation on archive page which have specific Description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I want to show product variation on archive page but the trick is that I want to show only variations which have a specific description I mean if I have four variations in a product like sm, lg, xl, xxl in which sm and xxl have a description like "I recommend this size"
than I want only sm and xxl show on shop page not lg and xl.